# How to specify each integer of the length of an array from 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I've been working on a website for several days now, with no knowledge of javascript whatsoever: I've managed to create a sort of slideshow gallery with changing captions, images, and respective background colors that is randomized each time the page is refreshed and doesn't repeat itself. That was the hard part, I think.

http://dreamquesting.neocities.org/

Now it's a matter of optimizing the code. In the shuffle function's execution, you can see a list of numbers as an array representing the min and max values of the variable arrays for backImage, etc.

I was curious if anyone knows a way, perhaps creating a function, to list integers from 0 to the last integer in a specified array such as backImage in this case, so that when I add more to the gallery, I don't have to keep adding the max value to the list.

I imagine there's an easier way to do the variable arrays backImage, backArtist, etc., but I'm not really sure what direction to take.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```js
var backImage = new Array();
var backArtist = new Array();
var backCaption = new Array();
var backColor = new Array();

backImage[0] = "https://dfep0xlbws1ys.cloudfront.net/thumbs71/df/71dfd3bb82eb215b00dd0bf1eb1be93d.jpg?response-cache-control=max-age=2628000";
backArtist[0] = "http://loish.net/dawn/";
backCaption[0] = "Breathe by Loish";
backColor[0] = "#52686F";

backImage[1] = "https://cdn2.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/000/768/254/large/eytan-zana-the-arrival.jpg?1443928283";
backArtist[1] = "https://www.artstation.com/artwork/the-return-a0dcbc0a-6be8-41cd-830b-34db8da07f85";
backCaption[1] = "The Return by Eytan Zana";
backColor[1] = "#4A4D56";

backImage[2] = "http://orig00.deviantart.net/f36b/f/2012/094/6/c/plains_of_glass_by_noahbradley-d4v1aab.jpg";
backArtist[2] = "http://noahbradley.deviantart.com/art/Plains-of-Glass-293992787";
backCaption[2] = "Plains of Glass by Noah Bradley";
backColor[2] = "#4D223C";

backImage[3] = "http://orig08.deviantart.net/6298/f/2015/032/c/2/hope_by_len_yan-d8g5zgm.jpg";
backArtist[3] = "http://len-yan.deviantart.com/art/hope-510882502";
backCaption[3] = "Hope by Len-Yan";
backColor[3] = "#A49576";

backImage[4] = "https://dfep0xlbws1ys.cloudfront.net/thumbs5a/19/5a192bf053eab38849419b9807346354.jpg?response-cache-control=max-age=2628000";
backArtist[4] = "https://www.inprnt.com/gallery/jjcanvas/pilgrimage/";
backCaption[4] = "Pilgrimage by Jorge Jacinto";
backColor[4] = "#10140A";

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

var mix = shuffle([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);

function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
  document.body.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 7px #000";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backColor[whichImage];
  document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];
  document.getElementById("caption").textContent = backCaption[whichImage];
  document.getElementById("artist").href = backArtist[whichImage];
  document.getElementById("everything").onclick = function() {
    changeBGImage(random);
  }
  var random = mix.pop();
}
```

Edit: In clarification: "As for the integer thing: I mean, you know with how the variable array of backImage in the example has part [0] through part [4]? And in the variable 'mix', shuffle lists those parts: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. I have to type those manually atm but was wondering if there was perhaps a function that would look something like integers.backImage()."

Comment: *"a way...to list integers from 0 to the last integer in a specified array"* I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, can you clarify?

Comment: Why dont you used json format for data storage? each element will store the information you have. So, randomize them will be easier..

Comment: can you clarify with example?

Comment: @FadhlyPermata: This is JavaScript code, so JSON wouldn't be relevant. Array and object initializers, though, would be very relevant, yes.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure what json is, I'll check it out. I know that my webhost here allows javascript and jquery so far, so I'll see what I can find out. As for the integer thing: I mean, you know with how the variable array of backImage in the example has part [0] through part [4]? And in the variable "mix", shuffle lists those parts: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. I have to type those manually atm but was wondering if there was perhaps a function that would look something like integers.backImage().

Comment: @resriel: FYI: http://pastie.org/10883703

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sorry, I am just suggesting him for the faster result.

Comment: Still can't figure out what you want the function to do.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you T.J. I wasn't exactly sure how to do it, but I knew it had to be easier and possible. Edit: The function would simply return the array integers representing each segment as such: "0, 1, 2, 3, 4".

Comment: OK, I'll try to create simple app for him. Just wait a minute

Comment: Would it perhaps have something to do with the backInfo"[index]" ...part? I think the "index" is what I've been trying to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function would simply return the array integers representing each segment as such: "0, 1, 2, 3, 4"

Ah, you're trying to get an array of the indexes so you can use it on this line:

```
var mix = shuffle([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

...instead of the literal array there. You can do that with `Object.keys`, like this:

```
var mix = shuffle(Object.keys(backImage));
```

It gives you an array with the "keys" of an object; arrays are objects, and their indexes are their keys, illustrated here:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

---

Now that I understand the question, the rest of this is irrelevant, but perhaps helpful to you separate from the question, so I'll leave it:

But if your goal is to loop through your arrays, you can use `forEach`:

```js
var backImage = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var backArtist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
backImage.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  console.log("image:", entry);
  console.log("artist:", backArtist[index]);
});
```

The above would be better with an array of objects, though, like [that Pastie I sent you](http://pastie.org/10883703):

```js
var backInfo = [
  {
    image: 'a',
    artist: 1
  },
  {
    image: 'b',
    artist: 2
  },
  {
    image: 'c',
    artist: 3
  },
  {
    image: 'd',
    artist: 4
  },
  {
    image: 'e',
    artist: 5
  }
];
backInfo.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log("image:", entry.image);
  console.log("artist:", entry.artist);
});
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm going to see what I can do with these already-existing functions. I just needed a list of integers, the keys, for each info section, to plug into the shuffle function I have in my code. Thanks, T.J.

Comment: I tried simply plugging it in: var mix = shuffle([Object.keys(backInfo)]); but I'm not sure it's that simple. It's not doing anything on my end, really.

Comment: Tried this as well: var mix = shuffle([console.log(Object.keys(backInfo))]); but no luck.

Comment: @resriel: `Object.keys` returns the array, so you don't want to put its result between `[` and `]` as that will put it inside *another* array. So: `var mix = shuffle(Object.keys(backInfo));`

Comment: Turns out I just had to remove the ['s. var mix = shuffle(Object.keys(backInfo)); works perfectly. Thanks for all your help!! Edit: beat me to it, ha.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've not testing this. but i think this will work as you expected result. Try to change your script just like this.

```
    var images = [{
    backImage: "https://dfep0xlbws1ys.cloudfront.net/thumbs71/df/71dfd3bb82eb215b00dd0bf1eb1be93d.jpg?response-cache-control=max-age=2628000",
    backArtist: "http://loish.net/dawn/",
    backCaption: "Breathe by Loish",
    backColor: = "#52686F"
}, {
    backImage: "https://cdn2.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/000/768/254/large/eytan-zana-the-arrival.jpg?1443928283",
    backArtist: "https://www.artstation.com/artwork/the-return-a0dcbc0a-6be8-41cd-830b-34db8da07f85",
    backCaption: "The Return by Eytan Zana",
    backColor: "#4A4D56"
}, {
    backImage: "http://orig00.deviantart.net/f36b/f/2012/094/6/c/plains_of_glass_by_noahbradley-d4v1aab.jpg",
    backArtist: "http://noahbradley.deviantart.com/art/Plains-of-Glass-293992787",
    backCaption: "Plains of Glass by Noah Bradley",
    backColor: "#4D223C"
}];

var randomized = images.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

console.log(randomized);
console.log(randomized[1]);
```